# How to create simple tableview and load data using Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an app for iOS using Swift but running into problems with the very basics.

To keep it simple I just want the app to initially be a single view application with a button and some sort of list view on the page.  I believe a TableView is what is recommended here.  When I click the button, I just want it to populate the list/table view with some entries, that's it.  To start with, I don't care if these entries are hard-coded, I just want to get something working.

I have been looking at different samples but I am getting confused.  Some of them seem to suggest using a TableViewController others don't.  When I use a tableview controller, the UI I had created seems to get completely replaced with just an empty tableview list and the button is gone.

I previously have developed apps in Windows phone and found it a lot easier.  I'd just add a listview object and in the click method of button, add the items programmatically etc.  But this is my first time trying to create an iOS app and it seems a lot more confusing.  There are delegates, controllers, views all seemingly needed in order to do something very simple.

Can anyone give me some basic step by step instructions about how to add a tableview to an application and load some data into it through a button click?

Comment: A table view controller is a UIView Controller with all of the tableview delegate and datasource methods set up for you. A table view is a view without a controller, and more difficult to set up. If you don't know what that means, close this question (you're already getting down votes), and google "UITableViewController tutorial". Sorry, but 'the basics' are too broad to teach here.

Comment: Hope [this doc](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/791/uitableview/2718/basic-table-view-example#t=201703082022407393333) helps.

Comment: If you are new to iOS / macOS development you should follow a tutorial and it will become obvious and easy how to use the frameworks. I recommend the free `Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift` on iTunesU (from Stanford) but there are hundreds (maybe thousands?) of tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are clear about the difference between a view and a view controller.

iOS uses the MVC design pattern (Model View Controller).

- A view object displays contents to the user and responds to user interaction.
- A model object stores state data.
- A controller object drives the app logic and mediates between the model and the view.

A `UITableViewController` is a special subclass of a UIViewController who's job is to manage a table view. It has some extra support in it that makes it a good choice for managing a table view, BUT... there is one annoying thing about it. It is designed so the ONLY view it can manage is a table view. You can't use a `UITableViewController` if you want to add buttons, labels, and other UI elements to your screen outside of the table view.

What I usually do is to create a create a table view controller, create a separate regular view controller, add a container view to the regular view controller, and then use an embed segue to embed the table view controller inside the view controller. (you just control-drag from the container view to the table view controller.) That way you get the best of both worlds. You may want to create a protocol that the table view controller would use to communicate with it's parent view controller.

You should be able to find a tutorial online on setting up a table view controller as a child of another view controller using container views and embed segues. It's quite easy.